# How to stop Lubuntu popup notifications

Tags: lubuntu, notification

(Running Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

For the last few months I've been getting annoying popups from certain activities. For example, Yakuake runs from autostart whenever I boot my PC. Now I get this popup to say it's started:

[image]

If I change a Dropbox file on another computer, I get this popup:

[image]

When I get an email, I get something like this popup:

[image]

These messages only last 3-4 seconds, but they overlay whatever you're doing, making them a nuisance.

I've used Lubuntu for years and I think they started with the 16.04.3 LTS update -- but I'm not certain. The point is, I never used to get them but I can't seem to switch them off!

Comment: You can click the Lubuntu ones to dismiss them as well.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that link but notification-daemon isn't installed. DK Bose's answer (below) solved my  problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that each application may provide means to control the notifications you see.

When you right-click on the Dropbox icon, choose `Preferences`, `Notifications`. Adjust the settings there.

[image: Dropbox notifications]

In the case of Yakuake, click on the downward pointing arrow in the lower right corner, see [this illustration](https://williamarchibaldspooner.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/yakuakeparts.png) to open `Main Menu` and then on `Configure Notifications` and adjust what you want.

[image: Yakuake notifications]

For Thunderbird, click on `≡` near the top-right corner, then on `Preferences` and choose `Account Settings`. In the left column of the window that appears, click on `Server Settings` and turn off `Allow immediate server notifications ...`.

[image: Thunderbird notifications]

You can also tweak certain aspects of the on-screen notifications by running `xfce4-notifyd-config` because Lubuntu uses `xfce4-notifyd`. A window will appear that allows you to

- choose from available themes
- set the default position
- the on-screen duration
- set the transparency (if you have a compositing manager such as Compton installed)

[image: Configure on-screen notification]